# preg-match for repeated characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to validate a string that can have lower-case characters and dashes but not at the beginning nor the end nor repeated. Then can have numbers too, but not at the beginning.

This is how it should work:

```
Match: ab9cd-a9bc-abbbc95
Not match: 5abcd
Not match: abbcd-
Not match: -abcd
Not match: abcd--abcd
```

I have been able to do everything but the last case, where a repeated dash shouldn't match.

I have this:

```
/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9\-]+[a-z0-9]$/
```

And I tried this but didn't work as expected:

```
/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9\-?]+[a-z0-9]$/
```

Comment: By saying "have lower-case characters and dashes but not at the beginning nor the end nor repeated", do you mean that only dashes are subjected to the `not at the beginning nor the end nor repeated" limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:-?[a-z0-9]+)*[a-z0-9]$
```

**example:**

```
$arr = array('ab9cd-a9bc-abbbc95','5abcd','abbcd-','-abcd','abcd--abcd');
foreach($arr as $str) {
    if (preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:-?[a-z0-9]+)*[a-z0-9]$/', $str)) {
        echo "OK : $str\n";
    } else {
        echo "KO : $str\n";
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
OK : ab9cd-a9bc-abbbc95
KO : 5abcd
KO : abbcd-
KO : -abcd
KO : abcd--abcd
```

**explanation:** (from YAPE::Regex::Explain)

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:-?[a-z0-9]+)*[a-z0-9]$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z0-9]*                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
                           (0 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -?                       '-' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z0-9]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z0-9]                 any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

`^[a-z](?:[a-z\d]|[a-z\d]\-)*[a-z\d]+$`

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/mE8pB8

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-z](_?[a-z0-9])*$/
```

dummy dummy

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one solve your problem

```
/^[a-z0-9]+((\-{0,1})[a-z0-9]+)+$/
```

Edited:

Following is more suitable

```
/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9]+((\-{0,1})[a-z0-9]+)+$/
```

Comment: @ka ᵠ What you mean in "pointless". Anyway i edited my post. Thanks.

Comment: `-` alone will match 1 dash, no need to 'force' the limit to 1 character with `{1}`